# Compare current month to same month last year in Excel pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I am creating a Sales Report for our Executive team, and the request with the most priority appears to be comparing sales in a given month to the sales in the same month of the previous year.

I have a linked data source (SQL server) for my data.  I know how to create a month to month comparison, but I don't know how to create a month/year to month/previous-year comparison.

I have Google searched for this, but I can only find month-over-month or year-over-year comparisons.

Here is what my source data looks like:

```
ReportDate  |  SalesYear  |  SalesMonth  |  CustomerMasterGroupNumber  |  CustomerMasterGroupName  |  ItemMasterGroupNumber  |  ItemMasterGroupName  |  ItemGroupNumber  |  ItemGroupName  |  ItemNumber  |  ItemDescription  |  TotalShipped  |  TotalSales
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-01-01     2014          1              8001                          CustomerGroupA              1002                      ItemMasterGroup 1       0007                ItemGroup 1       140216         Widgets             110              1814.84
2014-04-01     2014          4              8001                          CustomerGroupA              1002                      ItemMasterGroup 1       0007                ItemGroup 1       140216         Widgets             167              2755.18
2014-07-01     2014          7              8001                          CustomerGroupA              1002                      ItemMasterGroup 1       0007                ItemGroup 1       140216         Widgets             127              2095.34
2015-01-01     2015          1              8001                          CustomerGroupA              1002                      ItemMasterGroup 1       0007                ItemGroup 1       140216         Widgets             101              1801.84
2015-04-01     2015          4              8001                          CustomerGroupA              1002                      ItemMasterGroup 1       0007                ItemGroup 1       140216         Widgets             196              3496.46
2015-07-01     2015          7              8001                          CustomerGroupA              1002                      ItemMasterGroup 1       0007                ItemGroup 1       140216         Widgets             158              2818.72
2016-01-01     2016          1              8001                          CustomerGroupA              1002                      ItemMasterGroup 1       0007                ItemGroup 1       140216         Widgets             130              2319.2
2016-04-01     2016          4              8001                          CustomerGroupA              1002                      ItemMasterGroup 1       0007                ItemGroup 1       140216         Widgets             142              2533.36
2016-07-01     2016          7              8001                          CustomerGroupA              1002                      ItemMasterGroup 1       0007                ItemGroup 1       140216         Widgets             148              2640.32
```

I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: What does your data look like? Comparisons will be essentially the same: All that changes is that you've specifying what two sets of data to compare.

Comment: @music2myear I have edited my question to include some sample data